# Django, ForeignKey to non unique field?

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to have a reference field (normally it is a foreignkey field)

`parent` field is the reference field.

Following is the simplified models to show what I'm trying to do.
For a given class Foo, I'd like to create another class FooCopy that can hold many copies of Foo.

(FooCopy.id, FooCopy.user_edit) pair is unique.

```
class Foo(Base):

    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        null=True, blank=True
    )


class FooCopy(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    user_edit = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        null=True, blank=True,
        to_field='id',
        db_constraint=False,
    )


foo = Foo.objects.create()


foo_data = model_to_dict(foo)

foo_copy1 = Foo.objects.create(user_edit=user1, **foo_data)
foo_copy2 = Foo.objects.create(user_edit=user2, **foo_data)


def model_to_dict(obj, exclude=[]):

    data = {}
    for f in obj.__class__._meta.get_fields():
        if f.name in exclude:
            continue
        if f.one_to_many:
            continue

        if isinstance(f, ForeignKey):
            field_name = "{}_id".format(f.name)
        else:
            field_name = f.name
        data[field_name] = getattr(obj, field_name)

    return data
```

I'm getting an error saying Foo.id needs to be unique.

(FooCopy.id must set unique=True because it is referenced by a foreign key.)

Is there a relational field I could use to reference another django model instance without the restriction above? (Or could I get away with it somehow?)

All I need is the ability to use `foo` and `foo_id`, I don't need the referential integrity of ForeignKey.

-- edit

After reading  Daniel Roseman's comments I think I can have

```
parent_id = models.IntegerField()

@property
def parent(self):
  return  self._default_manager.get(id=parent_id, user_edit=self.user_edit)
```

Although I will probably miss some of stuff that django provides for foreignkey such as `parent__name` etc, I'm not sure if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Why would you have a ForeignKey pointing to a non-unique ID value? What would you expect to happen when you get a linked item with an ID that is not unique?

Comment: @Alasdair: thanks for the input, I just tried, and it's the same as before.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, I'm making a copy of original instance. I can create more than one copy. hence I have `id` field as integer field, and separate `_id` autofield. As I said in the op, I actually don't want "ForeignKey", I need a field that I can use as in `bar.foo` and `bar.foo_id` as I could do with foreignkey

Comment: But that didn't answer my question. If you have two Foo instances with `id=2`, and a Bar with `bar.foo_id=2`, and you do `bar.foo`, what do you expect to be returned?

Comment: that's right.. You spotted my flaw.. I've updated the op with the intended usuage. (foo_id, user) pair is unique, So I need to retrieve the bar.foo with the foo_id and user pair I guess. Thank you very much. Please let me know if you have more to say to my edited question.

Comment: Yeah, a method/property looks like the way to go. Alternatively you might look at this package, which claims to be able to support composite foreign keys: http://django-composite-foreignkey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (disclaimer: never used it).